# Can't open csv file in python without opening it in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a .csv file generated by a program. When I try to open it with the following code the output makes no sense, even though I have tried the same code with not program generated csv and it works fine.

```
g = 'datos/1.81/IR20211103_2275.csv'
f = open(g, "r", newline = "")
f = f.readlines()
print(f)
```

The output of the code looks like this

```
['ÿþA\x00l\x00l\x00 \x00t\x00e\x00m\x00p\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00 \x00°\x00F\x00.\x00\r',
 '\x00\n',
 '\x00\r',
 '\x00\n',
 '\x00D\x00:\x00\\\x00O\x00n\x00e\x00D\x00r\x00i\x00v\x00e\x00\\\x00M\x00A\x00E\x00S\x00T\x00R\x00I\x00A\x00 \x00I\x00M\x00E\x00C\x00\\\x00T\x00e\x00s\x00i\x00s\x00\\\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00o\x00s\x00\\\x001\x00.\x008\x001\x00\\\x00I\x00R\x002\x000\x002\x001\x001\x001\x000\x003\x00_\x002\x002\x007\x005\x00.\x00i\x00s\x002\x00\r',
```

However, when I first open the file with excel and save it as a .csv (replacing the original with the .csv from excel), the output is as expected, like this:

```
['All temperatures in °F.\r\n',
 '\r\n',
 'D:\\OneDrive\\MAESTRIA IMEC\\Tesis\\datos\\1.81\\IR20211103_2275.is2\r\n',
 '\r\n',
 '",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,"\r\n',
```

I have also tried csv.reader() and doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what's going on and how can I solve it? How can I open my .csv without opening and saving it from excel first? The source program is SmartView from Fluke which reads thermal image file .is2 and converts it into a .csv file

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Try opening in notepad/text editor and see whether the characters are displayed properly before saving using excel.

Comment: Looks like characters are having \x00 or null byte.

Comment: `open(r"datos/1.81/IR20211103_2275.csv", encoding="utf16", newline="")` It's UTF-16 encoding, so you need to specify it, @DanielGomez. Also I'd recommend you to use `with` working with files, check [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Hello @AllenJohnson. When I open it in notepad the characters are displayed properly without the \x00 bite

Comment: Ok @DanielGomez, Check Olvin's comment, That is the solution.

Comment: Hello @OlvinRoght. Your suggestion worked perfectly!! It's UFT-16 indeed. Thank you very much. Would you please post it as an answer to accept it?

Comment: @DanielGomez, I've posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69905322/10824407).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is encoded with [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) *(Little Endian byte order)*. You can specify file encoding using `encoding` argument of [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function *(list of standard encodings and their names you can find [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings))*.

Also I'd recommend to not use [`.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) as it will keep trailing newline chars. You can read all file content into as string *(using [`.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read))* and apply [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to ... split string into a list of lines. Alternatively you can also consume file line by line and call [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to cut trailing newline chars.

**Final code**:

```py
filename = "datos/1.81/IR20211103_2275.csv"
with open(filename, encoding="utf16") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    # OR
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
g = 'datos/1.81/IR20211103_2275.csv'

f = open(g, "r", newline = "",encoding="utf-16")

f = f.readlines()

print(f)
```

try this one it may help

Comment: It won't help as it is not UTF-8 but UTF-16.